# Map string to integers with position in ASCII table

Tags: python, string, numpy, unicode, vectorization

I have a string like this:

```
word = 'python'
```

Based on `string.ascii_lowercase`, I'd like to create a new array which looks like this:

```
[15, 24, 19, 7, 14, 13]
```

My solution for this problem was to do the following:

```
alphabet = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}
indices = [alphabet[char] for char in word]
print(indices)
```

Output: `[15, 24, 19, 7, 14, 13]`

But I'm looking for a more efficient way, without using loops. How can I do that in a **vectorized** way?

Comment: `[ord(c) - 0x61 for c in word]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght It's not a vectorized way. It's using list comprehension.

Comment: I know, but it's fastest way you can do that using python.

Comment: Is this the typical size string?  Or are you working with strings that are much longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to build an array from the string using `np.fromiter` and specifying a 'U1' dtype, cast to integer, and subtract the starting position of the alphabet in the unicode table, `97` or we can just use `ord('a')`: as suggested by Antoine Dubuis:

```
import numpy as np
word = 'python'
np.fromiter(word, dtype='U1').view(np.uint32) - ord('a')
array([15, 24, 19,  7, 14, 13])
```

Comment: Are you sure `np.fromiter` is doing a vectorized operation here? Going by the docs, seems like a generic utility, might be something like `np.vectorize`?  Then by the runtime numbers, seems to be scaling linearly w.r.t. the size of input, suggesting iterating one at Python level.

Comment: Yes, judging by the runtime numbers it definitely seems so, the difference is huge. I would've thought the creation of the array, which should be `O(n)` of course in both cases, is a necessary step in any case, and goes down to C. It might be that forcing the dtype to `U1` and then casting is just much slower. Or perhaps more along the lines of what you say, and that it is mostly a convenience function. Unsure though @divakar

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`np.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) for a pretty efficient one -

```
import numpy as np

np.frombuffer(word.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)-97
```

Timings on a `1M` long string :

```
In [23]: import string

In [24]: p = string.ascii_lowercase

In [25]: word = ''.join([p[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,len(p), 1000000)])

In [26]: %timeit np.frombuffer(word.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)-97
136 µs ± 1.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# @yatu's soln with np.fromiter
In [27]: %timeit np.fromiter(word, dtype='U1').view(np.uint32) - ord('a')
24.8 ms ± 423 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```